# Check if referenced field exists in commerce product display

Tags: theming, commerce

I have to render different types of product (with different fields combinations) in a generic product display `tpl` file. 
I created an array with all possible field names (they all are referenced `product:field_name`) which passes through a

```
if ($content[$my_field]){
  //some code
}
```

that is supposed to check if the field exists and then do things...

The problem is that it actually checks the existence of the field but shouts out a `notice: undefined index` warning for every field that is not present.

Is there a way to execute this check in a cleaner way?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @aram-boyajyan for improving formatting of the question!
I don't know if it's better to ask another question or maybe integrate this one... actually after checking if the field exists I need to check if it's empty too and I can't understand how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you should check if that element exists; here's how:

```
if (isset($content[$my_field])) {
  //
}
```

This way if the field is not set, you won't get the `undefined index` error.

Comment: Yes, actually that is not throwing out the error anymore. thanks!