# Checking if referenced fields are empty in commerce product display node.tpl

Tags: theming, commerce

I have a list of fields in a product display `node.tpl` that are references from different product types, any one of which has a combination of some of the fields of the list.
I pass the list of fields through a check to see if they exist (already answered in [Check if referenced field exists in commerce product display](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194072/check-if-referenced-field-exists-in-commerce-product-display) ) and then I need to find a solution to check if any of this field is empty to avoid showing it in a dynamic accordion.
In that `tpl`file I reach the fields with `$content['product:field_name']`

I'm a little lost here, I've tried using some of `field_*_field()` drupal functions but I can't seem to get to the product.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can render the field in advance, and save the html for your accordion.

the html variable will be empty if the field is empty:

```
$html = render($content['product:field_name']));
if (!empty($html)) {
  // accordion stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks! pretty straightforward actually, but I don't know why I was complicating it more than it needed! cheers!